# Update table column wiht unique string using where exist statment

Tags: mysql

I have unique column url varchar(4), and want to update it to unique random string, but having problems with duplicated items.
So I want to create loop something like this, but having problem with targeting twice same table.

```
UPDATE IGNORE word SET url = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(SUBSTRING('1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm' , 1+ FLOOR(RAND()*LENGTH('1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'))     ,1) SEPARATOR '')   
FROM (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS dummy_tbl) 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT url FROM word WHERE url IS NULL);
```

What is the best way to fill my column, with single query?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `EXISTS` clause and just update the `NULL` rows directly:

```
UPDATE
IGNORE word
SET url = ...
WHERE url IS NULL;
```

So your full query would be:

```
UPDATE
IGNORE word
SET url =
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(SUBSTRING('1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm', 
      1+ FLOOR(RAND()*LENGTH('1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm')),1) SEPARATOR '')
     FROM
         (SELECT 1
          UNION SELECT 2
          UNION SELECT 3
          UNION SELECT 4) AS dummy_tbl)
WHERE url IS NULL;
```

Comment: I was try that before I add EXISTS clause, it not update all rows just some of them, and when its duplicated entry they leave NULL. So I basically wanted to add loop with that EXISTS. (I have ~250k rows and doing alter table url column)

Comment: I'v extend my substring/lenght with same character x3 size and its update it in single query, but I want to see correct loop code for the future projects.

Comment: You cannot loop in an `UPDATE` statement. You would need to write a script to do that, or a stored procedure.